# RShiny - Render text string in renderHighchart() when there is no chart

Tags: r, rshiny

We have something like the following in our RShiny server:

```
output$our_graph <- renderHighchart({
  our_data <- get_our_data() # this is a reactive
  if(nrow(our_data) == 0) {
    return('Sorry no data')
  }

  our_return_graph <- highchart(...stuff)
  return(our_return_graph)
})
```

Currently this throws an error since it seems we are not allowed to return the character string 'Sorry no data' from within `renderHighchart` (which makes sense). Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** I don't think we can conditionally render the entire `our_graph` from the UI, because whether or not the graph renders depends on what the `get_our_data()` returns, which is not available in the UI. If possible, we'd like to handle this on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I move this if statement over the render function, precisely I added a `validate(need(` combo.

```r
data <- reactive({
  our_data <- get_our_data() # this is a reactive
  validate(need(nrow(our_data) == 0, "Please select a data set"))
  our_data
})


output$our_graph <- renderHighchart({
  data() ...
  our_return_graph <- highchart(...stuff)
  return(our_return_graph)
})
```

Source:https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/validate.html

You might check the `shinyalert` for clear and descriptive communication with users.

Comment: Good idea. I realized also that for simplicity we can simply build the error into a highchart (blank chart with error in title). This is helpful too. We are also adding `shinycssloaders` and other features to improve the UX for end users. Thanks